# Set Column Count dynamically in a horizontal Report

Tags: jasper-reports

I hava a horizontal report and I need to set the Column Count field dynamically, before run the report.

Is that possible? How?

Comment: crosstab is the way to go or dynamic jasper...

Comment: I read that, but I don't know if I can put a subreport inside a crosstab. And that is what I need